# how to open new activity when scan QRcode?

Tags: android, qr-code

how to open a new activity after scanning QRcode where each QRcode has one activity. here is my code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents() == null){
                Toast.makeText(this, "sambel sere", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                Intent inten = new Intent(ReaderActivity.this, sambel.class);
                startActivity(inten);
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: Have you declared your Activity class (sambel) in AndroidManifest.xml?